# Pass index value between two ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I've two arrays of differently structured JSON; which look like:

```
divisions:
    {
      title: string,
      text: string
    }[],
```

and:

```
featureSection:
    {
      headingName: string,
      features: string[]
    }[]
```

I need to create DIVs which look like (for divisons):

```
<div id="highlight-features" class="py-5 " *ngFor="let data of retrievedDATA.responseJSON.divisions; let odd=odd; let index = index let even=even" [ngClass]="{ 'bg-white': odd, 'bg-light-secondary': even }">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">

      <h2>{{ data.title }}</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="lead">{{ data.text }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and (for features section):

```
<div id="featureDiv" class="py-5 bg-light-secondary">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto" *ngFor="let features of retrievedDATA.responseJSON.featureSection">
      <h2>{{ features.headingName }}</h2>
      <br>
      <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let feature of features.features">{{ feature }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem i face is to make the odd-even bg-white and bg-light-secondary consistent across the two sets of ngFor, as the number of divisions and featureSections can change at any time so; i figure if i can pass the index of last em to the next ngFor i can make it work but i am unable to figure out how to pass the index

Comment: can you show a screenshot of  your current result and your expected result?

Comment: We need more explanation about the issue, so we can help.

Comment: Can you please post StackBlitz

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/W44R7Gcg/photo-2019-03-07-13-12-18.jpg it seems fine now; but if i add another object in divisions, the last element of the divisions section will be having the class bg-light-secondary making it and the features section div having the same color; which i want to avoid as the number of objects in divisions will be dynamic which can break the pattern reducing readability and affecting the UI